# Why is the Hashref passed to the Net::Ping constructor, set to an empty hashref after Net::Ping->new($args)?

Tags: perl, ping, strawberry-perl

What am I missing here?

When passing arguments to Net::Ping like this, then $args and $args_copy will both be set to an empty hashref after initializing the constructor Net::Ping->new($args).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use Net::Ping;

sub _ping {
    my ($args) = @_;
    my $p = Net::Ping->new($args);
    $p->close();
}

my $args      = { proto => 'udp' };
my $args_copy = $args;

print Dumper $args;                         # $VAR1 = { 'proto' => 'udp' }
print Dumper $args_copy;                    # $VAR1 = { 'proto' => 'udp' }
_ping($args);
print Dumper $args;                         # $VAR1 = {}
print Dumper $args_copy;                    # $VAR1 = {}
```

I see the same behavior on both Strawberry Perl and WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with Perl v5.30.0.

Comment: Hah, interesting.  You pass a reference to the constructor, and I assume it gets cleared, for some reason, on `close()` or scope exit (by desctructor perhaps).  Pass a copy then, `_ping( { %$args });`, if having `$args` cleared is a problem.

Comment: @zdim Thank you! That solved my problem! I never thought about such a simple solution. I just stumbled up on this while writing a test _ping.t, where I wanted to update some arguments before creating a new object.
Since this was posted as a comment, how do I accept this answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is interesting, a class (constructor) deleting caller's data.

The shown code passes a reference to the `Net::Ping` constructor and that data gets cleared, and right in the constructor (see below).

To avoid having `$args` cleared, if that is a problem, pass its copy instead

```
_ping( { %$args } );
```

This first de-references the hash and then constructs an anonymous hash reference with it,<sup>†</sup> and passes that.  So `$args` is safe.

The constructor [new](https://metacpan.org/dist/Net-Ping/source/lib/Net/Ping.pm#L95) uses data from `@_` directly (without making local copies), and as it then goes through the keys it also [deletes them](https://metacpan.org/dist/Net-Ping/source/lib/Net/Ping.pm#L131), I presume for convenience in further processing.  (I find that scary, I admit.)

Since a reference is passed to `new` the data in the calling code can get changed.<sup>‡</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> When copying a hash (or array) with a complex data structure in it -- when its values themselves contain references -- we need to make a *deep copy*.  One way is to use [Storable](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable) for it

```
use Storable qw(dclone);

my $deep_copy = dclone $complex_data_structure;
```

Here that would mean `_ping( dclone $args );`. It seems that `new` can only take a reference to a flat hash (or scalars) so this wouldn't be necessary.

---

<sup>‡</sup>  When a sub works directly with the references it gets then it can change data in the caller

```
sub sub_takes_ref {
    my ($ref_data) = @_;

    for my $k (keys %$ref_data) {   
        $ref_data->{$k} = ...;      # !!! data in caller changed !!!
    }    
}

...

my $data = { ... };  # a hashref

sub_takes_ref( $data );
```

However, if a local copy of arguments is made in the sub then caller's data cannot be changed

```
use Storable qw(dclone);  # for deep copy below

sub sub_takes_ref {
    my ($ref_data) = @_;
  
    my $local_copy_of_data = dclone $ref_data;

    for my $k (keys %$local_copy_of_data) {   
        $local_copy_of_data->{$k} = ...;   # data in caller safe
    }
}
```

(Just remember to not touch `$ref_data` but to use the local copy.)

This way of changing data in the caller is of course useful when the sub is meant to work on data structures with large amounts of data, since this way they don't have to be copied. But when that is not the purpose of the sub then we need to be careful, or just make a local copy to be safe.